# Vue Webpack configuration doesn't minify images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, configuration

So I am working on a simple card game, where i have like 40 images relate to the cards. I am using Vue Cli that already comes with a simple webpack configuration.

**So basicly I am saving all the images on the static folder like this:**

[image: static folder structure]

When I build the project for production, generating the **dist** folder, it creates the images like this:

[image: dist folder]

this is my webpack production file:

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
  ? require('../config/test.env')
  : require('../config/prod.env')

const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true,
      usePostCSS: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? config.build.devtool : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          warnings: false
        }
      },
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      parallel: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css'),
      // Setting the following option to `false` will not extract CSS from codesplit chunks.
      // Their CSS will instead be inserted dynamically with style-loader when the codesplit chunk has been loaded by webpack.
      // It's currently set to `true` because we are seeing that sourcemaps are included in the codesplit bundle as well when it's `false`, 
      // increasing file size: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/1110
      allChunks: true,
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: config.build.productionSourceMap
        ? { safe: true, map: { inline: false } }
        : { safe: true }
    }),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // keep module.id stable when vendor modules does not change
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    // enable scope hoisting
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks (module) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    // This instance extracts shared chunks from code splitted chunks and bundles them
    // in a separate chunk, similar to the vendor chunk
    // see: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#extra-async-commons-chunk
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'app',
      async: 'vendor-async',
      children: true,
      minChunks: 3
    }),

    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

Any help would be appreciate, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you used [`vuejs-templates/webpack`](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack), which does not include image optimization out of the box. You can easily add this (with `imagemin-webpack-plugin`) in your Webpack config:

1. Install [`ImageminWebpackPlugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-webpack-plugin) with: `npm i -D imagemin-webpack-plugin`
2. In `build/webpack.prod.conf.js`, import the plugin, and configure it in `plugins[]` (after `CopyWebpackPlugin`):

   ```
   const ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;

   const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
     plugins: [
       // ...
       new ImageminPlugin({
         test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
         /* other ImageMin configs */
       })
     ]
   }
   ```

Running `ImageminWebpackPlugin` after `CopyWebpackPlugin` ensures the copied images from `static` are run through ImageMin optimization.

[GitHub repo demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-webpack-imagemin-demo)

Comment: I am getting 5 vulnerabilities from Image Minimizer. Can it still be used in production?

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of Vue you can use a `vue.config.js` that looks like this:

```
const ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new ImageminPlugin({
        disable: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

This will enable Imagemin on production builds but skip on development builds.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try. It will help you minify images automaticlly without complicated algorithm configurations. It can also help you to encode(and inline) images (behave more flexible than url-loader).

https://github.com/GaoYYYang/image-optimize-loader

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|webp|git|svg|)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'img-optimize-loader'
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```